# Android Studio Java Bluetooth LE doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I have my Arduino advertising BLE, I can download, "BLE Scanner" app to connect to it and it works that way. Now I'm writing app on Android to connect to that Arduino. I've got following code but it doesn't work:

```
ScanCallback scanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
  @Override
  public void onScanResult(int callbackType, final ScanResult result) {
    super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
    System.out.println("Callback: " + callbackType);
  }

  @Override
  public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
    super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
    System.out.println("callback error");
  }
};

BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);

BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

BluetoothLeScanner mLEScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();

ScanSettings scanSettings = new ScanSettings.Builder().setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY).build();

mLEScanner.startScan(null,scanSettings,scanCallback);
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
I/BNRClientProivder, VERSION : 1.7.5: register - xml6 quick_backup : ACCESSIBILITYSETTINGS, X6qErjsfs2, com.android.settings.accessibility.sharedaccessibility.scloud.BNRTask
I/QBNRClientHelper: init SyncClientHelper : ACCESSIBILITYSETTINGS
I/BNRClientProivder, VERSION : 1.7.5: register - xml6 quick_backup : CONNECTIONS, C0phMaUuZZ, com.android.settings.wifi.mobileap.WifiApBackupRestore
I/QBNRClientHelper: init SyncClientHelper : CONNECTIONS
I/BNRClientProivder, VERSION : 1.7.5: register - xml6 quick_backup : WiFi, C0phMaUuZZ, com.android.settings.wifi.WifiBackupRestore
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessibility settings seems like permissions. You need to allow for ble features within the application.

- Go to your manifest file add bluetooth permissions and location permissions

Then you will need to grant the app permissions when you run it. Go to your open apps and press the 3 dots, app info, permissions location enable.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Also I cant see what the scan result it. On a ble scan callback you get the device address, scan record(advert data) and the rssi(power received).

Comment: I don't understand this sentence "Go to your open apps and press the 3 dots, app info, permissions location enable.", is it in Android Studio or phone itself?

Comment: So in your android phone there is a bottom in the bottom right. Press it and it will show you all your open applications. Which you can then use to select the app or close it. You also have an icon in the top right of this next to the app tile. It is 3 dots in a straight line. Press this and you can go to the application info. From there allow location permissions. Or go to your phone settings -> apps and notifications-> See all apps -> fine your app and enable location permission. Hope this helps.